# What determines the devices that google play will offer apps to?

Tags: android

I had assumed that if your manifest contains a line `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="X" />` then google play automatically knows to only show your app in the play store to people whose devices have android X or higher.... But I just recently tried out uploading an app (as beta) which contains `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />` but upon looking at the app in the store on a PC (visible only to invited beta testers), it says in the store listing "Requires android 1.6 and up". This has confused me because I thought that SDK8 corresponded to Android 2.2.

Comment: I have the same issue (showing as 1.6+ in app store). However I am using a minSDK of 11...

Comment: @MuhammadA: Is that with a beta release? I guess it could just be a google bug that only shows up for beta apps.

Comment: My app is in Alpha at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html) is the official documentation of filtering criteria, and [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels) is a list of all API levels.

The specific issue you have seems to be a bug with Google Play, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667093/google-play-wrong-minimum-api-detected) question (and a few more unanswered ones [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17501745/google-play-is-showing-wrong-api-level) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19152531/why-is-minsdkversion-ignored-by-google-play)).

Comment: But that documentation would indicate that my line <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" /> is correct, but why does the listing say  "Requires android 1.6 and up"?

Answer (score -1):

A the Goolge play store looks after our androidmaifest.com

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="X"
          android:targetSdkVersion="X" 
          android:maxSdkVersion="X"/>
```

as the min sdk tells that it will support from the api level and max sdk tell that it will support for that high level of devices.version. by looking after in the manifest files the Google play store will decide